# SQL query every 30 minutes triggers Android notification

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, alarmmanager

I already have a WebView application connecting clients to a mobile friendly website. For admins, I would like to have a functionality that will run a SQL query (that I already have) every 30 minutes. If it returns true I want a notification to be triggered.

I have done some research and have downloaded a JDBC driver to connect to my MsSql database.

I would like to know the best way to have the app run the query every 30 minutes and conditionally trigger a notification.

Any tips or help is appreciated.
Please let me know if this is a duplicate, I did search before posting.

TBG

Comment: Search "cron job" with the name of your platform after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) which allows you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future, in your case every 30 minutes.
Make sure you run your heavy query in the background using AsyncTask or something like that.

Check this to learn more about AlarmManager https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html and how to use it.

Comment: This is great, this would allow me to start a service and run it from the application's onStart, how could I go about starting the service from the device's boot?

Comment: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED